# Preventing default action in submit event handler is not working properly

Tags: jquery

I have built a script that seem to work properly, but when the form is submitted the appended data only flashes. I have put `return false` just before the end. What could be wrong?

```
$('#blankett_form').submit(function () {
    var id = $(this).find('.update:last').val();
    if (!id) {
        alert('Välj land och region.');
    } else {
        var table = '<table class="table table-hover table-bordered"><thead><tr><th>blanketter.</th><th>datum tillagt.</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>'
        $('#formsubmit').empty().append(table);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'func/blankett_func2.php',
            data: {
                'id': id
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data.list, function (index, value) {
                    $('#formsubmit tbody').append(value);
                });
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the first line to `$('#blankett_form').submit(function (e) {` and calling `e.preventDefault()` at some point within the function?

Comment: @Felix Kling Thank you for edit.

Comment: No I have not, but would I have to? I ran the script before I put the Ajax request in to see that the `var table` was appended properly. Then it worked.

Comment: What does the data being returned actually look like? If they're not `<tr>`s, it might not work as you expect..

Comment: The data that is being retuned are in <tr>, but even if they are not being retuned should `var table` not be appended?

Comment: @Noyo if you put your answer in a response I can close this question, because you where totally right! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the data being returned are `<tr>`s? If not, the table might not render as you expect, and that may be the cause of what you're seeing.